# Incorrect display of a PDF file when drawing using Core Graphics

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uikit, core-graphics

Faced with the problem of incorrect display of some PDF files when drawing using Core Graphics Context. Background blocks are drawn correctly but text is not displayed.

[image]

A quick analysis of the PDF file with the help of online tools showed that all the texts are saved as separate pictures with some strange resolution and dpi. But the logo image is fine.

[image]

The code for displaying a pdf file looks like this:

```
// #1 Load CGPDFDocument from file
guard let pdf = CGPDFDocument(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.path)) else { return }

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
    // #2 Enumerate a file pages
    for pageNumber in 1...pdf.numberOfPages {
        guard let pdfPage = pdf.page(at: pageNumber) else { return }

        var pageRect = pdfPage.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        // #3 Rendering current page
        var previewImage: UIImage?
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
            previewImage = renderer.image { ctx in
                // ...
                // #4 Draw PDF page on the context
                ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(pdfPage)
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
```

This issue happening on iPhone X (iOS 11) and iPhone 8 (iOS 11). But on a other devices this not occurs (include other devices with iOS 11).

Unless I'm mistaken incorrect processing pdf happens into the drawPDFPage function. But what's going on under the hood and what affects the result?  There are no errors in the log.

Did you have a similar problem? What are the workarounds for this issue?
Are there any alternative ways to draw a pdf from a file?

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

Starting with iOS 11 you can use [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit) for simple and convinient work with this file format. Code of getting UIImages from PDF pages in my app looks like:

```
var pageImages: [UIImage] = []

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    // iOS 11 approach
    // #1 Load PDFDocument using PDFKit
    if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: fileURL) {
       // #2 Enumerate a file pages
        while pdfDocument.pageCount > index {
            guard let pdfPage = pdfDocument.page(at: index) else { continue }
            // #3 Rendering current pages thimbnail 
            pageImages.append(pdfPage.thumbnail(of: self.canvasSize, for: .mediaBox))
            index += 1
        }
    }
} else {
    // iOS 10 and earlier
    // #1 Load CGPDFDocument from file
    guard let pdf = CGPDFDocument(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL.path)) else { return }

    // #2 Enumerate a file pages
    for pageNumber in 1...pdf.numberOfPages {
        guard let pdfPage = pdf.page(at: pageNumber) else { return }

        var pageRect = pdfPage.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        // #3 Rendering current page
        var previewImage: UIImage?
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
            previewImage = renderer.image { ctx in
                // ...
                // #4 Draw PDF page on the context
                ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(pdfPage)
            }
        }
        guard let preview = previewImage else { return }
        pageImages.append(preview)
    }
```

Don't forget to add `import PDFKit`.